# GSAP как сохранить параметры?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, gsap

Всех приветствую, проблема такая:
У меня на сайте в разработке есть кнопка, которая при скролле фиксируется вверху окна
и находится там при скролле вниз за границей вьюпорта, при скролле вверх эта кнопка выезжает.
Привёл пример на тайте, вниз - уезжает вправо, вверх - выезжает на обычное положение.

На пк всё работает исправно, но на телефоне - бажина,
я делаю скролл, кнопка уезжает, когда заканчивается процесс скролла, кнопка тут же возвращается на исходное место (не за вьюпортом, а по центру экрана).
Дамы и господа, кто сталкивался с этим и как это исправить?

```js
const showSpoller = gsap
    .fromTo(
        'h1',
        {
            // invalidateOnRefresh: true,

            paused: true,
            x: 100,
            duration: 0.2,
        },
        { x: '0%' }
    )
    .progress(1)
ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: 'h1',
    endTrigger: 'bottom',

start: 'top top+=20',
    pin: true,
    scrub: 0.5,
    end: 'bottom bottom',
  markers: true,
    pinSpacing: false,
    onUpdate: self => {
        self.direction === -1 ? showSpoller.play() : showSpoller.reverse()
        ScrollTrigger.saveStyles('.catalog__select-box')
    },
    // onUpdate: self => console.log('direction:', self.direction),
})
```

```css
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6rem;
    max-width: 32rem;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<div>
<br>
<br><h1>hello </h1>

<br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br><br>d<br></div>
```